# +colorWithPatternImage: should preserve transparency in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have a custom `NSView` that is used for displaying a background color. This works. However, I have shadows in that image that are not preserved.

All transparent or semi-transparent areas of the image are rendered as black. How do I fix this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSColor *pattern = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
    [pattern setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSRectFill()` is a shortcut for `NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeCopy)`. This means that it won't composite the color's alpha channel with the background, it simply draws the source color in the rectangle you pass in. Instead, you should use:

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

The `NSCompositeSourceOver` compositing operation will display the source image wherever the source image is opaque and the destination image elsewhere.