# Getting alpha to work on a NSColor using colorWithPatternImage

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nscolor

So I'm trying to get a repeating image onto a NSView using colorwithpatternimage. However when I do so I do not get the alpha of the image to come through as well, as you can see here:
[image]

here is the code so far:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set]; //setting up and drawing the background
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    [BkImage drawInRect: destRect fromRect: NSZeroRect operation: NSCompositeSourceOver fraction: 1.0];
    NSColor *PetalPattern = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:PetalImage]; 
    [PetalPattern setFill];
    NSRectFill (floatRect);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631493/colorwithpatternimage-should-preserve-transparency-in-cocoa